# Google Maps not loaded when there is no wifi on device

Tags: google-maps-mobile

I have a debug key for Google Maps api and built an application using it. I am testing the maps application on my device and it works fine only when there is wifi.

But it doesn't work when there is no wifi. It doesn't load the tiles. I read in another post stating I need a signed key to test on device. Is it required?

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know Google maps load it's data from the web. If there's no connection to the web you can't load the maps. Just make sure there's an working internet connection and try again.

Comment: Correct. Google Maps requires an stable internet connection.

Comment: Hi @Corstian Boerman, I tried it on my mobile using 3G. It just displayed black screen and after long time I get "..its taking time. Do you want to kill it????"not exactly but similar kind of message.

Comment: It also depends on your 3G connection speed. Most of the times an WiFi connection is much faster that an 3G connection. You can use [http://network.msu.edu/public/speedtest.html](http://network.msu.edu/public/speedtest.html) to compare your WiFi connection and 3G connection speeds.

Comment: I think it is not a problem with speed. Because I have google maps application and it works good on wifi or 3G.

Comment: Here you go. I waited till the last minute and finally maps loaded into my application taking 3MB of my data. why this is different from android in built default google maps app which loaded immediately once I opened the app??

Comment: Maybe that android app support caching of the maps. Just go to maps.google.com on your device and check how fast that's loading.